# Android:I want to use keys on the soft keyboard to control the movement of aircraft

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

An Android question:I want to use  keys on the soft keyboard to control the movement of aircraft.For example if I press the 's' key on the soft keyboard,the aircraft will move to the left. But I do not konw how to show the soft keyboard on the LinearLayout .At the same tiem there is not have the TextEdit.

Comment: At the same time there is not   the TextEdit.

Comment: Program's main UI divided into two sections, Made up of two LinearLayouts.The up LinearLayout aims to show the aircraft.The down LinearLayout aims to show the soft keyboard.I want to use keys on the soft keyboard to control the movement of aircraft.